# mysqldump specific table with table structure with where clause

Tags: mysql

I want to dump data from a specific table on a specific time period.

So I added a WHERE clause to the dump command. Now I also want to have the table structure so that when I import the SQL it wouldn't return an error. I used the following command:

```
mysqldump -t -u root -p  --host IP DBNAME TABLENAME --where="LastUpdate > '2018-01-09 00:00:00'" > result.sql
```

However the resulting SQL dump does not include the table structure. How to include the table structure when dumping from MySQL using `mysqldump`?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```bsh
mysqldump -u root -p --host IP DBNAME TABLENAME --where="LastUpdate > '2018-01-09 00:00:00'" > result.sql
```

Remove `-t` flag.

> [4.5.4 mysqldump — A Database Backup Program :: --no-create-info, -t](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-create-info)
>
> Do not write CREATE TABLE statements that create each dumped table.
>
> ...